# How to detect props.children.length and pass it as dependency in useEffect hook in typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

```
const panel=({children})=>{

  useEffect(()=>{
    update();
  },(children as ReactNode[]).length)

  return <div>.....</div>
}
```

Useeffect hook is not getting hit if length of children gets changed. How to detect the length of children and pass it as dependency. If length of children gets changed i need to execute one function

Answer (score 1):

can use the `Children`

```
import React, { Children } from "react";

const count = Children.count(children);
```

Comment: Is this the only way